# MYSQL duration between entries

Tags: mysql

I need to print out the entries in a MySQL database that happened over a 30minutes timeframe but they must have the same country. An sample of the database is shown below:

```
TIMESTAMP        RULE       COUNTRY  
2010-10-25 10:01:00 ICMP PING   SINGAPORE  
2010-10-25 10:25:00 ICMP PING   SINGAPORE  
2010-10-25 10:45:00 ICMP PING   MALAYSIA  
2010-10-25 11:00:00 ICMP PING   MALAYSIA  
2010-10-25 12:20:00 ICMP PING   UNITED STATES  
2010-10-25 14:30:00 ICMP PING   UNITED STATES
```

As above the records that came from SINGAPORE and MALAYSIA happened within 30mins, please help me with an SQL to display:

```
COUNTRY RULE  
SINGAPORE  ICMP PING  
MALAYSIA  ICMP PING
```

Comment: What if second USA entry was in 13:00 instead? What result set would be then?

Comment: If you look at the timestamp for the 3 different countries, only singapore and malaysia has 2 entries with the same rules and happaned within a 30mins timeframe. Hope this helped.

Comment: within 30 minutes of what?  the two US entires are 10 minutes apart; why are they excluded?

Comment: @zerkms, if the United States entry was 13:00, the difference in time between 12:20 and 13:00 would be 40mins, so it would still be only Singapore and Malaysia.

Comment: @ysth, oh its a big mistake on my part, i have edited my question, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Jeremy Oh: and what if there are 3 records for USA: 12:20 12:30 14:00?

Comment: @zerkms then it will display USA, cuz 1220 to 1230 is 10 mins, that is valid. 1230 to 1400 is not valid cuz its more than 30mins already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select distinct x.country, x.rule
    from yourtable x
    inner join yourtable y
        on x.country=y.country and x.rule=y.rule
        and y.timestamp > x.timestamp and y.timestamp < date_add(x.timestamp, interval 30 minute);
```

If exactly 30 minutes should be included, change the `<` to `<=`.

This assumes timestamps are unique (or at any rate that two "simultaneous" records don't count).  If that is not true, either a unique column to differentiate them or a different approach is needed.